# Is incrementing/decrementing a column from a large set of rows bad practice?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm designing a queue system and trying to decide between decrementing a column of a large set of rows or giving the row a priority and calculating the queue position with this.

That said, I'm wondering if decrementing a `position` column for a large set of rows is considered bad practice?

```
UPDATE <table>
  SET position = position - 1
  WHERE event = <event_id>;
```

Edit: To provide details on what I'm designing

I'm keeping track of who is next in line. If a car shop can only work on 3 cars at once then any new customer that shows up will need to wait in line. The ordering of these new customers is important as it is a first come first serve basis (FIFO).

When a garage opens up, the next person in line is popped off the queue and all other waiting customers get moved up one position in line.

Comment: Think about separate table `(event_id, position_deviation)`.

Comment: Regularly `UPDATEing` a large number of rows _for any reason_ is a sign of a poor Schema design.  Please elaborate on your reason -- do you need the numbers to be consecutive?  Do you sometimes increment, sometimes decrement?  What is the "priority" used for?  The "position"?  Doesn't the "priority" effectively determine the "position"?

Comment: @RickJames Added details on the problem I'm solving. Sounds like I should just use a priority that never changes and calculate the position in line when I need to.

Comment: message queue implementations provide a significantly better API for handling queueing than MySQL. Suggest just using the message queue (e.g RabbitMQ) for storing the MySQL primary key and do the rest of the processing in MySQL.

Comment: How about two columns -- a priority and a timestamp.  And have `INDEX(priority, ts)` so that the first row is the one to take.